# Customer attribute variable in email

Tags: customer, email

I am using an extension that allows me to add customer attributes to the registration page. Now I want to add the value that the customer fills in as a variable in the email. How do I find out the code to call the variable?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the customer attribute has the code `some_var_here`.
You can add this in the e-mail template:

```
{{var $customer.getSomeVarHere()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will add only value exists,

```
{{depend var $customer.attributecode()}}
     {{var $customer.attributecode()}}
 {{/depend}}
```